# How to close all the windows before the next test in a test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, rspec, selenium-chromedriver

```
[7] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> page.execute_script "window.close()"
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError: Script execution failed. Script: window.close();
 The window could not be found

[8] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> page.driver.browser.window_handles
=> ["f1-2"]
```

I had a browser open with two tabs, the above command does close one but the last tab never closes. It is open but when I try to run `page.execute_script "window.close()"` it gives the above error.

```
page.driver.browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(handle)
  page.execute_script "window.close()"
end
```

The above code  was working for me sometime back but doesnt work anymore. It gives the same error.

UPDATE:

When I use,

```
page.driver.browser.window_handles.each do |handle| 
   page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(handle) 
   page.driver.browser.close 
end
```

it gives the following error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: 'auto_id'` does not refer to an open tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.driver.browser.close` closes current tab towards the end and the last (second) tab closes itself after each example.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can do it

1. In line with your technique using JS. You would first need to switch back to your first browser window (window_handle) and then perform "window.close()". (Not Preferred) (Not sure why its not working now for you, did you upgrade server version or different browser?)
2. Simply use `@driver.quit` (Preferred)

**Update**

---

Just write this once. This will close all windows.

```
  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
  end
```

If  you want to close only one browser tab/window/popup, switch to that window_handle and then perform

```
@driver.close();
```

Comment: I used driver.quit at the end of each test and they failed with `An error occurred in an after hook
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError: getUrl execution failed;
 The window could not be found`

Comment: Do not do both, only option 2 and only once. Look at my update.

Comment: I have tried both individually. In each test, I open two windows and want to close them before the second test begins. Using `page.driver.quit` gives `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
       Connection refused - connect(2)`

Comment: When I use `page.driver.browser.window_handles.each do |handle|`
   `page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(handle)`
   `page.driver.browser.close`
  `end` , it gives the following error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       'auto_id' does not refer to an open tab`

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are using cucumber, you can the use the `BEFORE/AFTER` hooks .please refer [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967397/selenium-cucumber-opening-too-many-windows)
 for some more on cucumber,please refer this [Cucumber Hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks)