# Switch to new window handle in Rspec

Tags: rspec, cucumber, watir

I have tried different methods mentioned in links below but none is working.

I prefer method where we can switch to windows using window title, thats also not working

- http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows
- [Switch to popup windows in cucumber, capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983684/switch-to-popup-windows-in-cucumber-capybara)
- [How to close all the windows before the next test in a test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282399/how-to-close-all-the-windows-before-the-next-test-in-a-test-suite)
- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Window
- https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/21

PS: Its not a pop up its a new tab in same browser.

I am using `watir webdriver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For locating windows, Watir has a title locator. You can see an example for this (and other ways for switching windows) in the [watirspec](https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/window_switching_spec.rb#L42-L45):

```
it "finds window by :title" do
  w = browser.window(title: "closeable window").use
  expect(w).to be_kind_of(Window)
end
```